# Find final square in matrix walking like a spiral

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Given the matrix `A x A` and a number of movements `N`.

And walking like a spiral:

1. right while possible, then
2. down while possible, then
3. left while possible, then
4. up while possible, repeat until got `N`.

Image with example (`A = 8; N = 36`)

[image]

In this example case, the final square is `(4; 7)`.

My question is: Is it possible to use a generic formula to solve this?

Comment: I'm weak in terminology, so could you pleas explain what do you mean by 'generic formula'? Are you okay with recurring formula?

Comment: @Nyavro. I meant a way in which for any `A` and `N` it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to calculate the answer.

To do so, it will help to split up the problem into three parts.

*(Note: I start counting at zero to simplify the math. This means that you'll have to add `1` to some parts of the answer. For instance, my answer to `A = 8, N = 36` would be the final square `(3; 6)`, which has the label `35`.)*

*(Another note: this answer is quite similar to [Nyavro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33572422/824425), except that I avoid the recursion here.)*

---

In the first part, you calculate the labels on the diagonal:

- `(0; 0)` has label `0`.
- `(1; 1)` has label `4*(A-1)`. The cycle can be evenly split into four parts (with your labels: `1..7`, `8..14`, `15..21`, `22..27`).
- `(2; 2)` has label `4*(A-1) + 4*(A-3)`. After taking one cycle around the `A x A` matrix, your next cycle will be around a `(A - 2) x (A - 2)` matrix.

And so on. There are plenty of ways to now figure out the general rule for `(K; K)` (when `0 < K < A/2`). I'll just pick the one that's easiest to show:

```
4*(A-1) + 4*(A-3) + 4*(A-5) + ... + 4*(A-(2*K-1)) =
4*A*K - 4*(1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2*K-1)) =
4*A*K - 4*(K + (0 + 2 + 4 + ... + (2*K-2))) =
4*A*K - 4*(K + 2*(0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (K-1))) =
4*A*K - 4*(K + 2*(K*(K-1)/2)) =
4*A*K - 4*(K + K*(K-1)) =
4*A*K - 4*(K + K*K - K) =
4*A*K - 4*K*K =
4*(A-K)*K
```

*(Note: check that `4*(A-K)*K = 28` when `A = 8` and `K = 1`. Compare this to the label at `(2; 2)` in your example.)*

---

Now that we know what labels are on the diagonal, we can figure out how many layers (say `K`) we have to remove from our `A x A` matrix so that the final square is on the edge. If we do this, then answering our question

> What are the coordinates `(X; Y)` when I take `N` steps in a `A x A` matrix?

can be done by calculating this `K` and **instead** solve the question

> What are the coordinates `(X - K; Y - K)` when I take `N - 4*(A-K)*K` steps in a `(A - 2*K) x (A - 2*K)` matrix?

To do this, we should find the largest integer `K` such that `K < A/2` and `4*(A-K)*K <= N`.

The solution to this is `K = floor(A/2 - sqrt(A*A-N)/2)`.

---

All that remains is to find out the coordinates of a square that is `N` along the edge of some `A x A` matrix:

- if `0*E <= N < 1*E`, the coordinates are `(0; N)`;
- if `1*E <= N < 2*E`, the coordinates are `(N - E; E)`;
- if `2*E <= N < 3*E`, the coordinates are `(E; 3*E - N)`; and
- if `3*E <= N < 4*E`, the coordinates are `(4*E - N; 0)`.

Here, `E = A - 1`.

---

To conclude, here is a naive (`layerNumber` gives incorrect answers for large values of `a` due to float inaccuracy) Haskell implementation of this answer:

```
finalSquare :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)
finalSquare a n
    | Just (x', y') <- edgeSquare a' n' = Just (x' + k, y' + k)
    | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    k = layerNumber a n
    a' = a - 2*k
    n' = n - 4*(a-k)*k

edgeSquare :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)
edgeSquare a n
    | n < 1*e = Just (0, n)
    | n < 2*e = Just (n - e, e)
    | n < 3*e = Just (e, 3*e - n)
    | n < 4*e = Just (4*e - n, 0)
    | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    e = a - 1

layerNumber :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
layerNumber a n = floor $ aa/2 - sqrt(aa*aa-nn)/2
  where
    aa = fromInteger a
    nn = fromInteger n
```

Comment: There's [undoubtedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) a way to calculate `floor(sqrt(A*A-N))` or `floor(A-sqrt(A*A-N))` without actually using floating point arithmetic, but I'll have to chew on that one for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the possible solution:

```
f a n | n < (a-1)*1 = (0, n)
      | n < (a-1)*2 = (n-(a-1), a-1)
      | n < (a-1)*3 = (a-1, 3*(a-1)-n)
      | n < (a-1)*4 = (4*(a-1)-n, 0)
      | otherwise = add (1,1) (f (a-2) (n - 4*(a-1))) where
          add (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1+x2, y1+y2)
```

This is a basic solution, it may be generalized further - I just don't know how much generalization you need. So you can get the idea.

Edit

Notes:

1. The solution is for 0-based index
2. Some check for existence is required (n >= a*a)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose a relatively simple workaround here which generates all the indices in O(A^2) time so that they can later be accessed in O(1) for any N. If A changes, however, we would have to execute the algorithm again, which would once more consume O(A^2) time.

I suggest you use a structure like this to store the indices to access your matrix:

`Coordinate[] indices = new Coordinate[A*A]`

Where `Coordinate` is just a pair of `int`.

You can then fill your `indices` array by using some loops:
(This implementation uses 1-based array access. Correct expressions containing `i`, `sentinel` and `currentDirection` accordingly if this is an issue.)

```
    Coordinate[] directions = { {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1} };
    Coordinate c = new Coordinate(1, 1);
    int currentDirection = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int sentinel = A;
    int sentinelIncrement = A - 1;
    boolean sentinelToggle = false;

    while(i <= A * A) {
        indices[i] = c;
        if (i >= sentinel) {
            if (sentinelToggle) {
                sentinelIncrement -= 1;
            }
            sentinel += sentinelIncrement;
            sentinelToggle = !sentinelToggle;
            currentDirection = currentDirection mod 4 + 1;
        }
        c += directions[currentDirection];
        i++;
    }
```

Alright, off to the explanation: I'm using a variable called `sentinel` to keep track of where I need to switch directions (directions are simply switched by cycling through the array `directions`).
The value of `sentinel` is incremented in such a way that it always has the index of a corner in our spiral. In your example the sentinel would take on the values 8, 15, 22, 28, 34, 39... and  so on.
Note that the index of "sentinel" increases twice by 7 (8, 15 = 8 + 7, 22 = 15 + 7), then by 6 (28 = 22 + 6, 34 = 28 + 6), then by 5 and so on. In my while loop I used the boolean `sentinelToggle` for this. Each time we hit a corner of the spiral (this is exactly iff `i == sentinel`, which is where the if-condition comes in) we increment the sentinel by `sentinelIncrement` **and** change the direction we're heading. If `sentinel` has been incremented twice by the same value, the if-condition `if (sentinelToggle)` will be true, so `sentinelIncrement` is decreased by one. We have to decrease `sentinelIncrement` because our spiral gets smaller as we go on.

This goes on as long as i <= A*A, that is, as long as our array `indices` has still entries that are zero.

Note that this does not give you a closed formula for a spiral coordinate in respect to N (which would be O(1) ); instead it *generates* the indices for all N which takes up O(A^2) time and after that guarantees access in O(1) by simply calling `indices[N]`.

O(n^2) hopefully shouldn't hurt too badly because I'm assuming that you'll also need to fill your matrix at some point which also takes O(n^2).

If efficiency is a problem, consider getting rid off `sentinelToggle` so it doesn't mess up branch prediction. Instead, decrement `sentinelIncrement` every time the while condition is met. To get the same effect for your `sentinel` value, simply start `sentinelIncrement` at (A - 1) * 2 and every time the if-condition is met, execute:

`sentinel += sentinelIncrement / 2`

The integer division will have the same effect as only decreasing `sentinelIncrement` every second time. I didn't do this whole thing in my version because I think it might be more easily understandable with just a boolean value.

Hope this helps!